# Custom listview adapter is blank no textviews are seen on interface

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rw5l.jpg)This is my list_item layout and i think there may be some problem with this layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="15dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="india china tension" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/summary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        tools:text="Modi silent on china issue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is main activity

```
 package com.example.android.myapplication;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.widget.ListView;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Creating fake news reports
        ArrayList<News> news = QueryWeb.extractNews();

        //finding a layout reference{@link ListView}in the layout
        ListView newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);


        // Create a new adapter that takes list of earthquakes
        final NewsAdapter adapter = new NewsAdapter(this, news);

        // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
        // so the list can be populated in the user interface
        newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



 }
```

This is the array adapter
    package com.example.android.myapplication;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ammulu on 22-07-2017.
 */

public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<News> {


    /**
     * Constructs a new {@link NewsAdapter}.
     *
     * @param context     of the app
     * @param news is the list of earthquakes, which is the data source of the adapter
     */
    public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> news) {
        super(context, 0, news);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list item view that displays information about news at the given position
     * in the list of news
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if there is an existing list item view (called convertView) that we can reuse,
        // otherwise, if convertView is null, then inflate a new list item layout.
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.newslist_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Find the news at that position
        News currentNews = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView with view ID title
        TextView titleView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        //Display the title
        titleView.setText(currentNews.getTitle());

        // Find the TextView with view ID summary
        TextView summaryView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.summary);
        //Display the summary
        summaryView.setText(currentNews.getSummary());

        //Return the list item that is showing  the appropriate data
        return listItemView;

    }
}
```

Json parsing code i think the problem is here

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.util.Log;



import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class QueryWeb {


        /**
         * sample json response for news query
         */
        private static final String SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE = "{\\\"status\\\":\\\"ok\\\",\\\"source\\\": \\\"techcrunch\\\",\\\"sortBy\\\": \\\"top\\\",\"articles\": [{\\\"author\\\": \\\"Alexandra Ames\\\",\\\"title\\\": \\\"Coverage\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"Coverage | Sessions: Robotics - Cambridge, MA - July 17, 2017\\\",\\\"url\\\": \\\"https:\\/\\/techcrunch.com\\/events\\/sessions-robotics\\/coverage\\/\\\",\\\"urlToImage\\\": \\\"https:\\/\\/s0.wp.com\\/wp-content\\/themes\\/vip\\/techcrunch-2013\\/assets\\/images\\/techcrunch.opengraph.default.png\\\",\\\"publishedAt\\\": \\\"2017-07-14T00:02:35Z\\\"},\n" +

                                                            "{\\\"author\\\": \\\"Matthew Lynley\\\",\\\"title\\\": \\\"Dropbox CTO Aditya Agarwal is leaving\\\",\\\"description\\\": \\\"Aditya Agarwal, who came to Dropbox via its acquisition of Cove way back in 2012 and was given the CTO role last year, will be leaving the company. Agarwal..\\\",\\\"url\\\": \\\"https:\\/\\/techcrunch.com\\/2017\\/07\\/21\\/dropbox-cto-aditya-agarwal-is-leaving\\/\\\",\\\"urlToImage\\\": \\\"https:\\/\\/tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com\\/2017\\/07\\/dropbox-fb-departure.jpg?w=764&h=400&crop=1\\\",\\\"publishedAt\\\":\\\"2017-07-21T17:18:11Z\\\"}],\n" ;




        /**
         * Create a private constructor because no one should ever create a {@link QueryWeb} object.
         * This class is only meant to hold static variables and methods, which can be accessed
         * directly from the class name QueryUtils (and an object instance of QueryWeb is not needed).
         */
        private QueryWeb() {
        }

        /**
         * Return a list of {@link News} objects that has been built up from
         * parsing a JSON response.
         */
        public static ArrayList<News> extractNews() {

            // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
            ArrayList<News> newsArray = new ArrayList<>();

            // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
            // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
            // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
            try {


                // TODO: Parse the response given by the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE string and
                // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.
                JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE);
                JSONArray titleArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("articles");

                for(int i=0; i < titleArray.length(); i++ ){
                    JSONObject newRead = titleArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = newRead.getString("title");
                    String summary = newRead.getString("description");

                    // Create a new {@link News} object with the magnitude, location, time,
                    // and url from the JSON response.
                    News news = new News( title, summary);
                    newsArray.add(news);


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {  // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
                // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
                // with the message from the exception.
                Log.e("QueryWeb", "Problem parsing news JSON results", e);
            }

            // Return the list of earthquakes
            return newsArray;
        }
    }
```

activty main xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Layout for a list of news-->
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

Comment: So what is the problem that you are getting ?

Comment: 'some problem' is not possible to figure what is wrong. Please write the *exact* solution you are looking for.

Comment: in your `list_item layout` ,change your width and height to `wrap_content`

Comment: my screen just shows white layout dats it no textviews @ZeekHuge ...

Comment: i want textviews to appear on the screen instead of just a white layout :( @Karma

Comment: Can you try to print your `News` object when it is created ? inside the constructor. Just use `Log.d(TAG, "title is " + title);` and `Log.d(TAG, "data is " + summary);`

Answer (score 0):

How many items are in the data set represented by this Adapter.

```
public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> news) {
    super(context, 0, news);
}

@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return news.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The LayoutInflater is not working properly with parent in some cases. So change string

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.newslist_item, parent, false);
```

to:

```
listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.newslist_item, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first you need to create a local list in adapter.

```
List<News> news = new ArrayList();
```

Then in your constructor try this

```
public NewsAdapter(Context context, List<News> news) {
    super(context, 0, news);
    this.news = news
}
```

then override this

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return news.size();
}
```

This is how you set values in model class.

```
 News news = new News( title, summary);
 news.setTitle(title);
 news.setSummary(summary);
```

Then finally you add them to list of News type

```
newsArray.add(news)
```

And finally in adapter

```
titleView.setText(news.get(position).getTitle));
summaryView.setText(news.get(position).getSummary);
```

Comment: I think the problem id with you model class. Can you post that?